# iPhone sending invitations to appointments it didn't create

Tags: iphone, ms-office, gmail, calendar

Ok at work I received an appointment invite from a colleague in Outlook which I accepted. This event is an out of hours social event so I thought I would forward the invitation as an iCal event to my iPhone and add it to my Gmail calendar to keep things synced up. But when adding to my calendar my phone decided to send out an invitation to everyone who was invited to the original event inviting them to this event that had just been added to my phone.

So now not only does everyone in the office have my personal email address they also have a confusing second invitation from a random Gmail account to an event they had already accepted or declined.

Is there any way I can forward calendar appointments like this without my phone emailing everyone attending?

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly "late to the game", but since no answer has been accepted yet, my input might still be useful:

- the "meeting highjacking" you describe in your question is fairly well known with Exchange and the iOS calendar app; in fact it can be even worse where simply accepting an invite on your phone may make you the "owner" of the meeting; this seems to happen more often the larger the number of meeting attendees gets. This issue is so severe that in my company we discourage people from accepting meeting invites from their phones.
- as for the "butchered description" you describe in your answer: this, too is a well known issue between Exchange and the iOS calendar. iOS 8.3 supposedly fixed it, but since those cut off notes do not happen all the time, we do not have enough data yet at work to say for sure.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any bug report references which can be linked to from this question?

Answer (score 0):

Right the way I seem to have solved it is to just forward the appointment regularly in Outlook and not as iCal. This has added it to my calendar but totally butchered the description and I've had to rename some of it but it seems to have worked. It has been a lot more effort than manually adding it though.

If anyone still finds a better solution though that would be great,